# Azure data factory pipleline folder property

Tags: azure-data-factory

Azure data factory v2 allows to organize the pipelines using a folder structure in the UI. In the pipeline json there is additional property called "folder". I don't see such properly in the PipelineResource class. How de we programmatically set this property?

Comment: Hi,Sam,does my answer helps you?

Comment: Hi,Sam,if you think my answer helps you ,please mark it for answer,thanks

Answer (score 1):

You do could find the `Folder` property in PipelineResource Class here:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.management.datafactory.models.pipelineresource?view=azure-dotnet.

Please see this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.management.datafactory.models.pipelineresource.folder?view=azure-dotnet#Microsoft_Azure_Management_DataFactory_Models_PipelineResource_Folder) and [adf .net source code](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/f3f0681b1ff8f280bfbbb45316fd6ed3ffd9da9d/articles/data-factory/quickstart-create-data-factory-dot-net.md).

Answer (score 0):

If you didn’t find it, you need update the SDK version.